# Java. Array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

The problem is: i have this code:

```
public class Component {
public Component() {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }
 public double[] Shifts ;
 public double[][] Couplings ;

}

public class Decouplage {
 public Decouplage(double[] GroupShifts, double[][] GroupCoup) {
  AllComponents = new Component(); 
  AllComponents.Shifts = GetShifts(...blah-blah-bla...);
  AllComponents.Couplings = GetGouplings(...blah-blah-bla...);
 }

public Component AllComponents ; 
}
```

It works. 
But when I try to create an array AllComponents[10] of this class Component

```
 public class Decouplage {
 public Decouplage(double[] GroupShifts, double[][] GroupCoup) {
  AllComponents = new Component()[nComponents]; /////HOW MUST I PUT IN ONE LINE THE NUMBER OF ELEMENTS AND THE () FOR CONSTRUCTOR????
  for (int iCounter=0;iCounter<nComponents;iCounter++){
         AllComponents.Shifts = GetShifts(...blah-blah-bla...);
         AllComponents.Couplings = GetGouplings(...blah-blah-bla...);
  }
 }
public Component[] AllComponents ; 
}
```

it does not compile.

But if I ignore the constructor's ()

```
public class Decouplage {
 public Decouplage(double[] GroupShifts, double[][] GroupCoup) {
  AllComponents = new Component[nComponents]; /////IS IT LEGAL TO IGNORE CONSTRUCTOR, EVEN IF IT IS EMPTY????
  for (int iCounter=0;iCounter<nComponents;iCounter++){
         AllComponents.Shifts = GetShifts(...blah-blah-bla...);
         AllComponents.Couplings = GetGouplings(...blah-blah-bla...);
  }
 }
public Component[] AllComponents ; 
}
```

it can not resolve Shifts and Couplings as a fields...

What could you advise? 
Note: GetShifts() has nothing with a standard Java's getShift(). It is my own, it works well, i checked.

Thanx!

Comment: You shouldn't name your variables starting with a capital letter. Please follow Java conventions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two separate concepts here: creating an array of references, and creating instances of your class. So this line:

```
AllComponents = new Component[nComponents]
```

will create an array of `Component` references. Initially, all the references will be null. If you want to fill it with references to new instances, you'll have to follow that line with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nComponents; i++)
{
    AllComponents[i] = new Component();
}
```

EDIT: To reply to the comment, `AllComponents` is an array - it doesn't have a concept of `Shifts` or `Couplings`. If you need to set the shifts or couplings for the new component, you should use either:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nComponents; i++)
{
    AllComponents[i] = new Component();
    AllComponents[i].Shifts = // Code here
    AllComponents[i].Couplings = // Code here
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < nComponents; i++)
{
    Component component = new Component();
    component.Shifts = // Code here
    component.Couplings = // Code here
    AllComponents[i] = component;
}
```

or add parameters to the constructor for `Component` to take the shifts and couplings.

I'm assuming you're a newbie at Java, by the way, and only want help on this specific problem at the moment - when you're ready to move on, it would be worth looking at [Java coding conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/), and encapsulating your data more robustly. (Using public variables is generally a bad idea.)

Comment: Understood thanks.
but the correction to

  AllComponents = new Component[nComponents]; 
  for (int iCounter=0;iCounter<nComponents;iCounter++){
   AllComponents[iCounter] = new Component();
   AllComponents.Shifts = GetShifts(...);
   AllComponents.Couplings = GetGouplings(...);
  }

Did not help. 
Still: the error on the lines of "Shift" and "Couplings": 
 AllComponents.Shifts cannot be resolved or is not a field
 AllComponents.Couplings cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tell me please if i need to put smt in constructor of Component class?

Thank you

Comment: ooops... soryy. I dont know how to put well-formatted comments... :(

Comment: AllComponents is an array - you need `AllComponents[i].Shifts = ...` and `AllComponents[i].Couplings = ...`

Answer (score 1):

```
AllComponents = new Component[nComponents];
 for (int iCounter=0;iCounter<nComponents;iCounter++){
   AllComponents[iCounter] = new Component();
   AllComponents[iCounter].Shifts = GetShifts(...blah-blah-bla...);
   AllComponents[iCounter].Couplings = GetGouplings(...blah-blah-bla...);
```

ps : variable starting with uppercase == bad practice

Comment: I'd say that the variables being public is a more serious problem :)

Comment: Why?...
I was always separating them like this... Where can B a problem?

P.S. Thanx for the answer for main Q!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
   public Decouplage(double[] GroupShifts, double[][] GroupCoup) {
      Component AllComponents[] = new Component[nComponents];
      for (int i = 0; i < AllComponents.length; i++) {
          AllComponents[i] = new Component();
          AllComponents[i].Shifts = GetShifts();
          AllComponents[i].Couplings = GetGouplings();
    }
```